# Flask WTForms, how to create a custom input with additional textinput

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I want to override render for a DateField or TextField. I want to change it to a hidden input field and a text field. In text field I can pick a date in Persian calander but the corresponding timestamp is stored in the hidden inputfiled which is bound to database.

I tried to define a custom widget:

```
class MyDateInput(HiddenInput):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        main_inp = super(MyDateInput, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
        _name = field.name + "_obs"
        kwargs.setdefault("id", field.id + "_obs")
        obs_inp =  Markup('<input %s>' % self.html_params(name=_name, **kwargs))
        return main_inp + obs_inp
```

And using it like:

```
birth_date = TextField('ﺕﺍﺮﯿﺧ ﺕﻮﻟﺩ',
                         id='birth_date',
                         widget=MyDateInput(),
                         #render_kw={'disabled':''},
                         )
```

And call it like:

```
  {{ form.birth_date(class="form-control") }}
```

But it renders two TextFiled, each with a hidden input field! one is just below form tag and the other is where I called the tag!!! why is it like that?  And how can I solve this? Or if you know better solutions please provide.